# Authorize application service based on client IP address

Tags: c#, authorization, ip-address, interceptor, aspnetboilerplate

We have implemented some Application Service methods without any permission. How can we implement authorization based on client IP address for executing methods?

For example, this is `GetParsedData` method:

```
public GetParsedDataOutput GetParsedData(GetParsedDataInput input)
{
    return _cacheManager.GetCache(nameof(GetData)).Get(input.ToString(), () => gpd(input)) as GetParsedDataOutput;
}
```

How can we check user permission by IP address? Suppose that client with IP address `192.168.5.2` is granted permission to execute this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inject `IClientInfoProvider` to get `ClientIpAddress`.

## Authorize an authenticated user

Override `IsGrantedAsync` in [`PermissionChecker`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core/Authorization/PermissionChecker.cs):

```
public override async Task<bool> IsGrantedAsync(long userId, string permissionName)
{
    if (permissionName == MyClientIpAddressPermissionName)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => { return _clientInfoProvider.ClientIpAddress == "192.168.5.2"; });
    }

    return await base.IsGrantedAsync(userId, permissionName);
}
```

Usage:

```
[AbpAuthorize(MyClientIpAddressPermissionName)]
public GetParsedDataOutput GetParsedData(GetParsedDataInput input)
{
    // ...
}
```

## Authorize an anonymous user

Since `AbpAuthorize` requires a user, you should use a custom (i) attribute, (ii) interceptor, and (iii) interceptor registrar.

(i) Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ClientIpAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string AllowedIpAddress { get; set; }
}
```

(ii) Interceptor:

```
internal class ClientIpAuthorizationInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly IClientInfoProvider _clientInfoProvider;

    public ClientIpAuthorizationInterceptor(IClientInfoProvider clientInfoProvider)
    {
        _clientInfoProvider = clientInfoProvider;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var methodInfo = invocation.MethodInvocationTarget;
        var clientIpAuthorizeAttribute = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ClientIpAuthorizeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()
                        ?? methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ClientIpAuthorizeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (clientIpAuthorizeAttribute != null &&
            clientIpAuthorizeAttribute.AllowedIpAddress != _clientInfoProvider.ClientIpAddress)
        {
            throw new AbpAuthorizationException();
        }

        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

(iii) Interceptor registrar:

```
internal static class ClientIpAuthorizationInterceptorRegistrar
{
    public static void Initialize(IIocManager iocManager)
    {
        iocManager.IocContainer.Kernel.ComponentRegistered += (key, handler) =>
        {
            if (ShouldIntercept(handler.ComponentModel.Implementation))
            {
                handler.ComponentModel.Interceptors.Add(new InterceptorReference(typeof(ClientIpAuthorizationInterceptor)));
            }
        };
    }

    private static bool ShouldIntercept(Type type)
    {
        if (type.GetTypeInfo().IsDefined(typeof(ClientIpAuthorizeAttribute), true))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (type.GetMethods().Any(m => m.IsDefined(typeof(ClientIpAuthorizeAttribute), true)))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Initialize the registrar in your Application module:

```
public override void PreInitialize()
{
    ClientIpAuthorizationInterceptorRegistrar.Initialize(IocManager);
}
```

Usage:

```
[ClientIpAuthorize(AllowedIpAddress = "192.168.5.2")]
public GetParsedDataOutput GetParsedData(GetParsedDataInput input)
{
    // ...
}
```

You should be able to extend that yourself to allow/disallow multiple IP addresses.

To fallback on permission names for an authenticated user, add the permission name as a `string` property in the attribute. Then inject `IAbpSession` and `IPermissionChecker` in the interceptor to call the `IsGrantedAsync` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own injector service for IApplicationService. And just before the application service method executes, you can make pre-checks.

See how to implement the injection
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection